Emacs cursor settings not working in Debian running on WSL
I am running emacs on Debian bookworm on WSL (Windows Subsytem for Linux). I run emacs in a Window terminal. Everything works except the emacs cursor is very hard  to find. If you look carefully at the following image you can barely make out the cursor (it's in column 1, line 1):

I tried to change it to a box by adding the following to the .emacs file in my home directory:
(setq-default cursor-type 'box)

However, adding that line made no difference.
How do I set the cursor to be a blinking box in this context?

You are running Emacs inside of a terminal, so the variable cursor-type has no effect. It is the terminal that controls what the cursor looks like, not Emacs. You might check the visible-cursor variable instead. From chapter 15.21 Displaying the Cursor of the Emacs manual:
15.21 Displaying the Cursor
===========================

On a text terminal, the cursor’s appearance is controlled by the
terminal, largely out of the control of Emacs.  Some terminals offer two
different cursors: a visible static cursor, and a very visible blinking
cursor.  By default, Emacs uses the very visible cursor, and switches to
it when you start or resume Emacs.  If the variable ‘visible-cursor’ is
‘nil’ when Emacs starts or resumes, it uses the normal cursor.

You can read the manual inside Emacs by typing C-h i.
Honestly, you should just run the native Windows build of Emacs, which can display a normal GUI and can therefore display any type of cursor.

This was extremely helpful. I changed the cursor shape in the Debian profile under the Windows terminal setting and now it is very visible in terminal-based Emacs.

You can also run Emacs in WSL under X. I use VcXsrv as an X server to display Emacs frames, which works flawlessly.
